# Jenkins send email as a promotion action

Tags: jenkins

I want to send emails for certain promotions. The default email notification only sends after a build, not a promotion.

I tried the editable email notification (email-ext) as an action in a promotion and added my email but it said "No emails were triggered." on running the promotion. Is there a way to make it work?

I will have to fall back to a powershell action if email-ext doesn't work.

Comment: Same here with Jenkins v1.609.1 and Promoted Builds plugin v2.21.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Try the answer I added.

Comment: I tried it with _Always_ before, as well. But I better had looked into my e-mail account, too, rather than relying on the console output only. Unlike the post-build action e-mail notification the promotion e-mail notification doesn't print a corresponding message there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the email-ext with the "Always" trigger under advanced and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **[Any Build Step plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin)**, in the Promotion action, select Conditional Build step, select "Always" condition, and select Email-Ext action.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have that plugin installed

Comment: Jenkins is that type of software that is all about plugins.... Ask your admin to install it. If he declines, citing "unknown/insecure/untested plugin" concerns, tell him: *"you would really rather allow users to write arbitrary executable scripts in powershell, than use a community-reviewed and trusted open-source plugin?"*

Comment: I just tried the email-ext with the "Always" trigger and it worked. Thanks!